What is a FIDE "adjusted rating floor"?
The FIDE norm regulations use the phase "adjusted rating floor" without defining it in the same document, how is it defined?
What are the conditions for being allowed to raise a rating floor and by how much can it be increased, the document says:

No more than one opponent shall have their rating raised to this
adjusted rating floor

The USCF seem to have a totally different concept of rating floor, so don't confuse the two separate set of regulations when googling.

The document says this:

b. For the purposes of norms, the minimum rating (adjusted rating floor) for the opponents shall be as follows:
Grandmaster norm 2200
International Master norm 2050
Woman Grandmaster norm 2000
Woman International Master norm 1850
c. No more than one opponent shall have their rating raised to this adjusted rating floor. Where more than one opponent is below the floor, the rating of the lowest rated opponent shall be raised.
d. Unrated opponents not covered by 1.4.6b shall be considered to be rated 1400.

.d means that if a player is going for any norm and one of the opponents is unrated then that player's zero rating can be replaced in the calculations by the value 1400.
The other rules mean that if the lowest rated player the norm seeker plays has a rating below the rating norm then that player's rating can be substituted by the rating norm in the calculations.
So, say you are trying to get a GM norm and one your opponents (the lowest rated) is only rated 2100 then when you calculate your required score based on your opponents' average rating then you can use 2200 (the GM rating floor) instead of 2100 for that opponent.
Similarly, if you were seeking an IM norm and your lowest rated opponent was only rated 1900 then you could use 2050 (IM rating floor) instead of 1900 in your calculations.

Does "d" make any sence as the resulting game can't be counted in the 9 games,  and the game could be discarded if more then 9 games without "d"?

@Ringrose Sometimes it might be interesting to have a norm with 10 games including the 1400 opponent rather than 9 games wihtout them, because you need norm on a range of at least 25 games to get the title. More importantly, while you can discard the first or last games of a tournament for calculating a norm, I don't think you can discard a game played in e.g. round 5 while keeping rounds 4 and 6. So you might need to include the game with the non-rated opponent.
